# docker fails to start elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

Start command：

```
docker run --name elasticsearch --restart always -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx256m" -v /mydata/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml -v /mydata/elasticsearch/data/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data -v /mydata/elasticsearch/plugins:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins -d elasticsearch:8.2.0
```

Error message：

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml.5_UsZrgbT-ORzBHNjBfbEw.tmp -> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml: Device or resource busy
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:100)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:416)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:266)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1432)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.AutoConfigureNode.fullyWriteFile(AutoConfigureNode.java:1126)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.AutoConfigureNode.fullyWriteFile(AutoConfigureNode.java:1138)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.AutoConfigureNode.execute(AutoConfigureNode.java:687)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.AutoConfigureNode.main(AutoConfigureNode.java:157)
```

Comment: you need to give Elasticsearch more heap, 128-256MB is not enough. start with 512MB for min and max

Comment: That's not the problem

Comment: Check this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/85463

Answer (score 0):

When i add cluster.name it work for me

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```